# PHP file_get_contents repetitive usage to get images from XML

Tags: php, image

Website I'm developing is showing products on sale and a lot of them are being updated and imported from XML (imported/updated 2x a day).

The problem is with getting product images. Some of them do not display even if url is provided.

Some XML contain from tens of items to hundreds of them.

The code loops through each item, gets all the data and then the image.

Example code regarding getting the image :

```
if (@file_get_contents($i->image)) {

    $name = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.jpg';

    $img = $name;

    $url = $i->image;

    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/img/upload/Items/'.$name;

    @file_put_contents($destinationPath, @file_get_contents($url));

} else {
    // do something else if there is no image
}
```

1. Is my approach wrong here ?
2. Remote server can't keep up with file requests ? And before each request need some pause ?
3. If items are updated 2x daily I shouldn't bother with saving images locally and give img src the external url from XML ?
4. Better use cURL() ?
5. If approach is accepted what improvement in needs ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are fetching the image twice for no good reason (first time in the `if` condition, then a second time on the line with `file_put_contents()`).

Comment: @ShiraNai7 `If` statement and `file_get_contents()` is used to check if the image is provided if not it returns false and skips getting it from remote place.

Comment: @Collyl you should cache it in a variable before the `if` then refer to this variable both times instead. That way you should double performance.

Comment: Are you able to check the item folder? If you able check them images are saved or not which given in url.

Comment: @ankit if you are referring to images whose url is given in xml, then no, i can't get to that folder, only open them one by one in browser with given url.

Comment: @pgmann thanks, i'll try it.

Comment: no, i am asking about the folder where you save images.

Comment: @ankit Of course I can open those images which are saved locally, some of them can be displayed but others that are saved can't be displayed...